# Command to run job exclusively on a single instance in cfncluster-SGE scheduler

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, qsub, sungridengine

I would like to submit a job exclusively to a single node in cfncluster using SGE scheduler qsub option. 
Does anyone know the correct way to reserve or use full instance for a job in the cfncluster.

```
qsub -l hostname=node@123 script.sh
```

works but i dont want to specify the hostname as we would not know 
hostname of the node as it has not been spun up. is there any option to specify number of nodes or cores.Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your Torque version?

Comment: i am using sge scheduler. is there any option to specify the no of nodes/cores in sge scheduler?

Comment: Sorry, no idea; I'd refer you to the SGE docs.

Comment: When I need to do this, I request the maximum memory available on one node (using `-l h_vmem=...` in my setup). This means that once that job gets scheduled, nothing else will be able to get on that node until that job is complete.

Answer (score 2):

To have a job run on a specific node, specify `-l nodes=<nodename>[:ppn=][+<nodename[:ppn=]>...]`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify cores by using an appropriate pe.  It is conventional to set up a pe called smp that runs on only a single node.  So if
 you want 4 cores on a single node you submit with `#$ -pe smp 4` in the jobscript.  There is another convention that requesting a resource called exclusive will guarantee that your job is the only one on the node.  so adding `#$ -l exclusive=true` will prevent other jobs from running on the node.